# How to use Websphere liberty in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

I want to use Websphere liberty in spring boot application instead of tomcat server. If I am correct it is not supported out of the box. How can I configure spring boot/websphere liberty to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

Using the [Liberty app accelerator](http://liberty-app-accelerator.wasdev.developer.ibm.com/) you can download a zip containing a Maven buildable 'Spring Boot with Spring MVC' app as your starting point. Just run `mvn install` and you'll get the app running at http://localhost:9080/myLibertyApp/

Comment: Thank you !!! Its running and creating a war file. I would like to get an executable jar from it. Is it possible?

Comment: You can't embed WLP so no jar for you there, sorry.

Comment: I am trying to develop Microservices using Spring boot and want to build it as an executable jar with WAS liberty profile. Will Spring boot be supporting WLP out of the box in the future? Is it possible to customize Spring boot for WLP?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can now create runnable jar files with WebSphere Liberty.  You need v8.5.5.9 or higher.  Create a runnable jar this way:

```
server package {server name} --archive={jar name}.jar --include=minify,runnable
```

Resultant jar can be run as you'd expect:

```
java -jar {jar name}.jar
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. 
If I add swagger dependency(io.springfox) or spring batch (spring-boot-starter-batch) to the pom the tests are failing and server is not starting. Is there any documentation for App Accelerator? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Here's the official documentation on [Running a Liberty server from a JAR file](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_setup_jarserver.html?lang=en)

Comment: The above link is not working, updated link is https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_setup_jarserver.html

Answer (score 0):

Since very recently (May 2018) you can deploy a Spring Boot jar with Liberty, as it seems. See https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2018/05/11/spring-boot-applications-on-liberty/. Haven't tried it out yet, though.