# RSA premaster secret error when using webHDFS from BigInsights on cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights, biginsight-examples

I'm trying to execute the [spark+oozie+bluemix liberty example](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/BigInsights-on-Apache-Hadoop/tree/oozie_spark/examples/OozieWorkflowSparkGroovyBluemixDeploy) on the [OozieWorkflowSparkGroovyBluemixDeploy branch](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/BigInsights-on-Apache-Hadoop/tree/OozieWorkflowSparkGroovyBluemixDeploy) against a BigInsights for Apache Hadoop basic cluster.

The error I get when I try to access the application from a browser:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
```

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be due to the webHDFS certificate not being in the liberty truststore.  See here for more information: [Steps to configure Bluemix Liberty application to add a certificate to the Liberty trust store using a cf CLI workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920473/steps-to-configure-bluemix-liberty-application-to-add-a-certificate-to-the-liber)

UPDATE:

The issue was due to liberty not having unlimited encryption policies. Fixed with commit: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/BigInsights-on-Apache-Hadoop/commit/b78d12d5ea3ce5e43395cf8e7c1d094e1a9fc012